# How to use python's seaborn to plot CDF?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

When I use the sns.kdeplot and let culmulative=True, the error is

> Cumulative distributions are currentlyonly implemented in statsmodels.Please install statsmodels.

Even though I have already installed statsmodels.

Answer (score 5):

From [the source code](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/distributions.py), we can see that all Seaborn does is attempt to import

```
try:
    import statsmodels.nonparametric.api as smnp
    _has_statsmodels = True
except ImportError:
    _has_statsmodels = False
```

at a module level, and should `_has_statsmodels` be `False`, the `_univariate_kdeplot` function attempts to fall back on SciPy, which does not support cumulative distributions for this purpose.

So there is nothing murky happening in Seaborn here, you simply have an `ImportError` from an installation or setup issue regarding statsmodels.

Comment: Thank you! I restart my python and then it's fine.